# Javascript OOP subclass help and structure

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following code:

```
(function(){

    var DS = (function(){

        DS.prototype.queryDB = function() {
            alert('query database');
        };

        DS.prototype.openDB = function() {
            alert('open the database');
        };

    });

    window.DS = new DS;

})(window);
```

I can then call `DS.queryDB()` and `DS.openDB()` from my page which works fine.

What I want is to have a database class within `DS` to seperate the functions further.

I tried changing `DS.prototype.queryDB` to `DS.prototype.Database.queryDB` but that didn't seem to work. How can I best structure my code to allow for this?

Comment: As a first step: Put the `DS.prototype.X` assignments *outside* the constructor function. In your case it does not make a difference because you only have one instance, but it is conceptually wrong to have the assignment there.

Comment: Also, only wrap anonymous functions in brackets if you're executing it immediately.

Comment: Ok I have http://jsfiddle.net/aw5mC/ so far now. How do I create a subclass within DS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done .

Consider doing it something like this .

```
DS.prototype = {
    db : new Database()
}

function Database(){}

Database.prototype = {
    queryDb : function(){}
}
```